# Google Maps Geoencoding

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to geoencode an address using google maps, but having an issue with it.

When I am trying an address - ambience , gurgaon, india, it results some required responses, but when I am trying - ambience mall, gurgaon, india, it results back zero results.

this is the code with which I am trying -

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {})
```

here address is the string which I have writtern above.

The same string gives result when I enter on maps.google.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I also faced this from Google API. Actually, in http://maps.google.com when you search **"ambience mall, gurgaon, india"** it gives so many suggestions in the LHS menu with several markers a,b,c,d..., but **does not pop an exact marker**. So this address does not have any successful geocode results. But when a addreess [e.g. **gurgaon, india**] pops only one marker on http://maps.google.com, it 
does surely have a Geocode result.

I think you will be interested in using the suggestion API so that your users always search for a valid address. Visit http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html